# Python Script Executes Manually in CMD but Errors in Scheduler

Tags: python-3.x, scheduled-tasks

So, I have a python script, that I can run in cmd using python [path to script]

I have it set in scheduler, but it doesn't run through scheduler and finds an error.  Cmd closes out before being able to read the error.  I created a batch file to launch to script, and it shows an error that a package doesn't exist [lxml]. But, the package exists as the script will run when manually executed

Any thoughts?

Script scrapes data from a website, creates a dataframe, posts dataframe to a google sheet, then pulls the full google sheet that it posts to, turns that into a dataframe with all of the data, then creates a plotly graph, turns that plotly into an html file, then sends the html file to a SFTP server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
import sys
import platform
import imp

print("Python EXE     : " + sys.executable)
print("Architecture   : " + platform.architecture()[0])
#print("Path to arcpy  : " + imp.find_module("arcpy")[1])

#raw_input("\n\nPress ENTER to quit")
```

Run this to get the proper path to your Python.exe, and place this in Program/Script.

Then you need to verify that EVERY directory in your script starts at C:/ and works its way through the full path.